# Mysql timerange row neighbour

Tags: mysql, sql, time

have a table `(fruits)` like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| time         | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| fruit        | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

How can I select rows that have a "row neighbour" within the timerange of +/- 10 seconds?

This is my sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `fruits` VALUES (1,'2016-01-19 02:14:07','apple'),(2,'2016-01-19 02:14:13','banana'),(3,'2017-06-08 06:59:12','melon'),(4,'2017-06-08 06:57:12','strawberry');
```

This is my expected result set:

```
1   2016-01-19 02:14:07
2   2016-01-19 02:14:13
```

The rows with the id 3 and 4 have no neighbours within 10 seconds (+/-).

I thought I could do something like this:

```
SELECT TIME
FROM fruits
WHERE (DATE_SUB(TIME , INTERVAL 10 SECOND) > ANY
         (SELECT TIME
          FROM fruits))
  AND (DATE_ADD(TIME , INTERVAL 10 SECOND) < ANY
         (SELECT TIME
          FROM fruits));
```

Which didn't work out well and is very complicated.

Comment: Can you provide example data and expected result?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have added data and expected result.